# Difference between these two formulas

Tags: python, python-2.7

For calculating the mean/average;

```
sum(j) / len(j)
sum(j) / max(len(j), 1)
```

I came across the second one earlier, but as far as I can tell, they do identical things. Can anyone explain the difference, if any?

Answer (score 3):

The last expression is used in order to avoid dividing by `0`. By assuming j is a list, if the array is empty, you will get a `0/0` expression if `len(j)` is used on it's own which will lead to an `ZeroDivisionError`.

```
>>> j = []
>>> sum(j) / len(j)
ZeroDivisionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-2bf5531faf2b> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(j) / len(j)

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The `max(len(j),1)` will ensure that the divisor never will be 0 and no error raised:

```
>>> sum(j) / max(len(j), 1)
0.0
```

Comment: Oh okay I think that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, after looking over, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. How could the divisor ever be 0?

Comment: If the array is empty, len(j) = 0, which leads to sum(j) also being 0.

Comment: If the array j is empty, max(len(j,1) => max(0,1) = 1,

sum(0)/1 => 0/1 = 0

Comment: Sorry if my answer was a bit hard to understand. I'm quite new to this :)

Comment: Didrik is correct here. The `max` function takes a second argument (`1` here) that is returned if the first argument has a `False` value; `len(j)` is `0` if `j` is empty and `bool(0) == False`. So in essence the code does, as mentioned, assure that division by `0` won't occur.

Comment: I edited your question a bit to add some relevant code Didrik, hope you don't mind. Congrats on your first answer here :-)

Comment: Thanks guys! That makes sense now